# Removing buffer from AVAssetWriter before outputting to file

Tags: ios, video, ios7, avassetwriter, avasset

I have an app that is like Vine or Instagram Video and I am trying to delete the last recorded segment. I am using AVAssetWriter and appending the sample buffer to the asset writer input when recording but I want to allow users to delete the last sample buffer that was recorded.

Is there a way to remove buffer appended to AVAssetWriter? I check the documentation and there is no methods to delete buffer.

Comment: Any solution @Harry or Encore PTL?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a fixed sized FIFO queue to cache the recent buffers instead of writing them directly. If the user decides *not* to delete the last buffers, then you write the remaining buffers in the queue.